# Why is my JDA discord bot not recieving DM's and printing them out

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am attempting to make my first bug report discord bot with JDA and I am able to get the bot to DM the user but when the user responds nothing prints and I get no exceptions even though the methods I use for the receiving end is highlighted orange meaning I typed the method correctly

Here is my main method

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.User;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main extends ListenerAdapter{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, LoginException {
        JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault("NzY5NDAwMDA0NTExMDA2NzMx.X5Odlw.45gBjejxyTnbKaTfP2kS46RPGYw");
        builder.setActivity(Activity.playing("RoParty By Myself"));
        builder.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        JDA jda = builder.build();
        jda.awaitReady();
        jda.addEventListener(new Main());
    }


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event){
        User user = event.getAuthor();
        String rawMessage = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();

        if(rawMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("Ro") && !user.isBot()) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Party!").queue();
        }else if(rawMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("hello there") && !user.isBot()){
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("General Kenobi!").queue();
        }else if(rawMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("!report") && !user.isBot() && event.getChannel().getName().equals("bug-reports")){
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Please File Your Report In The DMs").queue();
            DMController dmController = new DMController(user, "Thanks for filling a bug report!");
        }
    }
}
```

here is my DM controller class

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.*;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.priv.PrivateMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.priv.PrivateMessageUpdateEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ErrorResponseException;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class DMController extends ListenerAdapter {

    private User user;
    private PrivateChannel channel;

    public DMController(User user, String startMessage) {
        this.user = user;
        this.channel = user.openPrivateChannel().complete();
        SendMessage(startMessage);
    }

    public boolean SendMessage(String message){
        try {
            channel.sendMessage(message).queue();
        }catch(ErrorResponseException ignored) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrivateMessageReceived(PrivateMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("responded");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create your DMController but you never add it as an event listener to JDA.

```java
DMController dmController = new DMController(user, "Thanks for filling a bug report!");
event.getJDA().addEventListener(dmController);
```

I would suggest changing your logic to use `queue()` instead of `complete()`. This can be done by making your class use the `PrivateChannel` as a constructor parameter instead:

**Constructor**:

```java
    public DMController(PrivateChannel channel, String startMessage) {
        this.user = channel.getUser();
        this.channel = channel;
        SendMessage(startMessage);
    }
```

**Usage**:

```java
user.openPrivateChannel().queue(channel -> {
  DMController dmController = new DMController(channel, "Thanks for filling a bug report!");
  event.getJDA().addEventListener(dmController);
});
```

You can remove the listener once you're done with [`JDA#removeEventListener`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#removeEventListener(java.lang.Object...)).